# How to build MPICH with gfortran-10?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, mpich

### TL;DR

How to build MPICH with gfortran-10, gcc-10 and g++-10?

### Background

I want to build MPICH with grortran-10 [so as to be able to use up to date MPI bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65750862/mpi-fortran-support-through-the-mpi-f08-module-with-gfortran), but I haven't managed to do so. Trying to install MPICH via apt on Ubuntu always uses gfortran 7.5.0 (same version with gcc and g++), even if I have latest version of gfortran installed. Just for clarity, here is my current MPICH and gfortran configuration (installed via apt) :

```
pavel@pavel:~$ mpiexec --version
HYDRA build details:
    Version:                                 3.3a2
    Release Date:                            Sun Nov 13 09:12:11 MST 2016
    CC:                              gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro 
    CXX:                             g++   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro 
    F77:                             gfortran  -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro 
    F90:                             gfortran  -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro 
    Configure options:                       '--disable-option-checking' '--prefix=/usr' '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--includedir=${prefix}/include' '--mandir=${prefix}/share/man' '--infodir=${prefix}/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var' '--disable-silent-rules' '--libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--with-libfabric' '--enable-shared' '--enable-fortran=all' '--disable-rpath' '--disable-wrapper-rpath' '--sysconfdir=/etc/mpich' '--libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--includedir=/usr/include/mpich' '--docdir=/usr/share/doc/mpich' '--with-hwloc-prefix=system' '--enable-checkpointing' '--with-hydra-ckpointlib=blcr' 'CPPFLAGS= -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -I/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2/src/mpl/include -I/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2/src/mpl/include -I/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2/src/openpa/src -I/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2/src/openpa/src -D_REENTRANT -I/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2/src/mpi/romio/include' 'CFLAGS= -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -O2' 'CXXFLAGS= -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -O2' 'FFLAGS= -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong -O2' 'FCFLAGS= -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong -O2' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'MPICHLIB_CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security' 'MPICHLIB_CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'MPICHLIB_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security' 'MPICHLIB_FFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong' 'MPICHLIB_FCFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro' 'FC=gfortran' 'F77=gfortran' 'MPILIBNAME=mpich' '--cache-file=/dev/null' '--srcdir=.' 'CC=gcc' 'LIBS=' 'MPLLIBNAME=mpl'
    Process Manager:                         pmi
    Launchers available:                     ssh rsh fork slurm ll lsf sge manual persist
    Topology libraries available:            hwloc
    Resource management kernels available:   user slurm ll lsf sge pbs cobalt
    Checkpointing libraries available:       blcr
    Demux engines available:                 poll select
```

```
pavel@pavel:~$ gfortran -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
```

With gcc and g++, it's the same as with gfortran in all relevant aspects.

Comment: Where is your gfortran 10 installed? How do you call it? How do you configure MPICH? It should be enough to use `FC=gfortran10 CC=gcc10 CXX=g++-10`.

Comment: @VladimirF gfortran (-v 7 installed during MPICH installation) : /usr/bin/gfortran

Comment: @VladimirF gfortran (-v 10 installed beforehand) : /usr/bin/gfortran-10

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to manually configure MPICH?

Comment: I normally only configure MPI. You just add those options to the `configure` command. I do not know if MPICH uses `configure`.

Comment: But at what point do I get to specify what compilator should be used? Must it be done during MPICH installation, or is it possible later?

Comment: During the compilation of MPICH. You must compile it from source. Or you must find some binary specifically configured for gfortran 10.

Comment: @VladimirF alright, I don't know how to do this, so I can't immediately tell you if that helped. I'll look into it, but if you could provide any guidelines, I would grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed advice VladimirF gave me in the comments, and everthing worked out. [This site](https://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Getting_And_Building_MPICH) provided all the necessary guidelines. Only a few minor problems had to be dealth with. Before I could create `./configure` file, I was prompted to install some missing autotools, which was simply done using `apt`. Once `./configure` file was ready, I passed in the mostly same configuration that `apt` originally installed MPICH with (see the long list original question), with `'FC = gfortran-10' 'CC = gcc-10' 'CXX = g++-10'` replacing `'FC = gfortran' 'CC = gcc' 'CXX = g++'`. Several more prompts had to be dealt with (mostly adding something to configuration or installing missing packages, easily done with Synaptic package manager). After doing all the steps, F08 bindings were succesfully built and work properly. Here is my current MPICH configuration :

```
pavel@pavel:$ mpiexec --version
HYDRA build details:
    Version:                                 3.4b1
    Release Date:                            unreleased development copy
    CC:                              gcc-10  -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -I/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2/src/mpl/include -I/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2/src/mpl/include -I/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2/src/openpa/src -I/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2/src/openpa/src -D_REENTRANT -I/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2/src/mpi/romio/include  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -O2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro 
    Configure options:                       '--disable-option-checking' '--prefix=/usr' '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--includedir=${prefix}/include' '--mandir=${prefix}/share/man' '--infodir=${prefix}/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var' '--disable-silent-rules' '--libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--with-libfabric' '--enable-shared' '--enable-fortran=all' '--disable-rpath' '--disable-wrapper-rpath' '--sysconfdir=/etc/mpich' '--libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--includedir=/usr/include/mpich' '--docdir=/usr/share/doc/mpich' '--with-hwloc-prefix=system' '--enable-checkpointing' '--with-hydra-ckpointlib=blcr' 'CPPFLAGS= -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -I/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2/src/mpl/include -I/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2/src/mpl/include -I/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2/src/openpa/src -I/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2/src/openpa/src -D_REENTRANT -I/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2/src/mpi/romio/include -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -I/home/pavel/mpich/src/mpl/include -I/home/pavel/mpich/src/mpl/include -I/home/pavel/mpich/modules/json-c -I/home/pavel/mpich/modules/json-c -D_REENTRANT -I/home/pavel/mpich/src/mpi/romio/include' 'CFLAGS= -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -O2 -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -O2' 'CXXFLAGS= -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -O2 -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -O2' 'FFLAGS= -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong -fallow-argument-mismatch -O2 -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong -O2' 'FCFLAGS= -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong -O2' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'MPICHLIB_CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security' 'MPICHLIB_CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'MPICHLIB_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security' 'MPICHLIB_FFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong' 'MPICHLIB_FCFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro' 'FC=gfortran-10' 'F77=gfortran-10' 'MPILIBNAME=mpich' 'CC=gcc-10' 'LIBS=' 'MPLLIBNAME=mpl' 'CXX=g++-10' '--with-device=ch3' '--cache-file=/dev/null' '--srcdir=.'
    Process Manager:                         pmi
    Launchers available:                     ssh rsh fork slurm ll lsf sge manual persist
    Topology libraries available:            
    Resource management kernels available:   user slurm ll lsf sge pbs cobalt
    Demux engines available:                 poll select
```

Comment: In case you encounter similar situation in the future, setting `CC`, `CXX`, `FC` (and in some cases `F90` or `F95`), and `LD` is the *de facto* standard way of specifying the components of the toolchain on Unix-like OSes. These environment variables are respected by practically any build tool in the Unix world--Make, GNU Autotools, and CMake, to name a few.