# Override flags specified by MPICH wrapper compiler

Tags: gfortran, flags, mpich

I'm trying to debug an MPI application written in fortran compiled with MPICH wrapper compiler. It compiles and runs, but at some point NaNs start poping out and it proved rather challenging to pinpoint exactly where it first happens. It would be helpful if I could compile my code with `-ffpe-trap=invalid`, but I'm not sure how to change the default set of flags, or wheter it's even possible.

From [OpenMPI FAQ entry on the matter](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=mpi-apps#override-wrappers-after-v1.0) and [MPICH README](https://github.com/pmodels/mpich/blob/main/README.vin), I've come to think it may be possible, but I don't quite understand how. I would rather not have to rebuild the library all over again with another set flags if another option exists. Is it possible, and if yes, how?

Just for clarity, my MPICH configuration is as follows (subject of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752900/how-to-build-mpich-with-gfortran-10), see the answer for how exactly it was installed)

```
pavel@pavel:~$ mpiexec --version
HYDRA build details:
    Version:                                 3.3a2
    Release Date:                            Sun Nov 13 09:12:11 MST 2016
    CC:                              gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro 
    CXX:                             g++   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro 
    F77:                             gfortran  -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro 
    F90:                             gfortran  -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro 
    Configure options:                       '--disable-option-checking' '--prefix=/usr' '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--includedir=${prefix}/include' '--mandir=${prefix}/share/man' '--infodir=${prefix}/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var' '--disable-silent-rules' '--libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--with-libfabric' '--enable-shared' '--enable-fortran=all' '--disable-rpath' '--disable-wrapper-rpath' '--sysconfdir=/etc/mpich' '--libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--includedir=/usr/include/mpich' '--docdir=/usr/share/doc/mpich' '--with-hwloc-prefix=system' '--enable-checkpointing' '--with-hydra-ckpointlib=blcr' 'CPPFLAGS= -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -I/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2/src/mpl/include -I/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2/src/mpl/include -I/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2/src/openpa/src -I/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2/src/openpa/src -D_REENTRANT -I/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2/src/mpi/romio/include' 'CFLAGS= -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -O2' 'CXXFLAGS= -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -O2' 'FFLAGS= -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong -O2' 'FCFLAGS= -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong -O2' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'MPICHLIB_CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security' 'MPICHLIB_CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'MPICHLIB_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security' 'MPICHLIB_FFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong' 'MPICHLIB_FCFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-O9at2o/mpich-3.3~a2=. -fstack-protector-strong' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro' 'FC=gfortran' 'F77=gfortran' 'MPILIBNAME=mpich' '--cache-file=/dev/null' '--srcdir=.' 'CC=gcc' 'LIBS=' 'MPLLIBNAME=mpl'
    Process Manager:                         pmi
    Launchers available:                     ssh rsh fork slurm ll lsf sge manual persist
    Topology libraries available:            hwloc
    Resource management kernels available:   user slurm ll lsf sge pbs cobalt
    Checkpointing libraries available:       blcr
    Demux engines available:                 poll select
```

Comment: Presumably you want to compile your program with that flag, rather than the MPI system itself.  Why do you want to set the compiler wrapper default flags to include `-ffpe-trap=invalid` rather than use it explicitly when compiling as required?

Comment: yeah, thats a good question. I somehow assumed I can't add more flags (probably because I didnt quite understand lingo in links). Well, thanks and sorry for stupid question, then :)